# How to show Apache logs using Rails programming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I am able to show production.log file using programming but could not show Apache logs.

This is how I am writing:

Controller:

```
  def logs
      lines = 1500
      @logs = `tail -n #{lines} log/production.log`
      @apache_access_logs = `tail -n #{lines} /var/log/httpd/access_log`
  end
```

View:

```
<button class="accordion">Production Logs</button>
<div class="panel">
  <pre><%= @logs %></pre>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Apache Access Logs</button>
<div class="panel">
  <pre><%= @apache_access_logs %></pre>
</div>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/httpd/access_log’ for reading: No such
>   file or directory

There are no .log extension in under apache. This is the full path of my file: **/var/log/httpd/access_log**

Please help how can show this log?

Comment: Does user under which rails is being run has access to `/var/log/httpd/access_log` file?

Comment: No. Actually we are having 2 servers. First is our side and the other one is from client side. They just gave  the path. Do we need to mention the authentication? IF yes, please tell how can I  do it?

Comment: So, you want to access apache logs from another server? If yes, [here is to get you started](https://www.google.com/search?q=tail+file+from+remote+server).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to show this log which is having full access then how it can be done?